# Why doesn't docker compose create container with container_name

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I created a Dockerfile and `docker-compose.yml` file.

I build image with tag "django-image".

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /code-django

COPY . /code-django

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db-money
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    image: django-image
    container_name: money
    volumes:
      - .:/code-django
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

In docker compose I have 2 services: "db" and "web". Docker compose creates "db" with "container_name: db-money" and starts it. Compose doesn't create another container with "container_name: money". Why doesn't the second "container_name" work?

[image: output in terminal, lsc is an alias of docker container ls -a]

Comment: Please don't paste picture URLs here. It's text that can be rendered nicely here.

Comment: How did you start your containers? By the container name `money-mangement_web_run_...` I'm led to believe you ran `docker compose run`

Answer (score 0):

Just execute:

```
docker compose up
```

inside the folder which contains docker-compose.yaml

Or -f pathToYourDockerComposeFile